# How do I extract business, advertisement and other reports from amazon MWS API?

Tags: amazon-mws

I understand how to extract order information from the MWS get_report function but nothing related to the business or the advertisement reports.

My intention is to periodically extract amazon ad related information(clicks,CTR...) and also business reports( sessions, buy box...). Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything you'd be able to get would be listed [here](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html) as a report type enumeration.  Out of the things you've asked about, the only possibility that I'm aware of is buy box information.  There is some of that in the [Products API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetCompetitivePricingForASIN.html) but the best place is to subscribe to the [AnyOfferChangedNotification](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_FR/notifications/Notifications_AnyOfferChangedNotification.html) which gives real time pricing updates with buy box information.

Comment: I did a quick google and found that there is a separate API for advertising.  Check it out here: https://advertising.amazon.com/API

Comment: Yep! I submitted a request a week back. I hope this API gives more information than the other one. Thank you for your help.